# Interactive shell stop pipe

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

My program is as follow:

```
//... init fd[2] as pipe ...
if (child==0){
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        execlp("/bin/sh","sh",NULL);
} else {
        close(fd[0]);
        char *line; int nbytes=100; int bytes=0;
        line=(char*) malloc(nbytes+1);
        while ( (bytes = getline((char **)&line,&nbytes,stdin))!= -1 ){
            write(fd[1],line, bytes);
        }
}
```

This run OK, however when I try to replace `exec("/bin/sh","sh",NULL)` with `exec("/bin/sh","sh","-i",NULL)` to force an interactive shell, my program stop after executing the first command.

I'm new to pipe so please help me understand the reason and make interactive shell work... I also feel that my code to read line and pass to the child pipe is a bit odd.. is there any better way to achieve the same behavior ?

Comment: Try closing all the file descriptors.  After dup2, close fd[0], and when you are done writing, close fd[1].

Answer (score 1):

You should `close(fd[0]);` after the `dup2()` in the child.  If you supply an absolute or relative path like `"/bin/sh"`, there's no point in using `execlp()`; it will only do a PATH-based search for a bare filename (program name).  The cast in the call to `getline()` should be unnecessary; avoid such casts whenever possible.  You should include at least `exit(1);` after `execlp()` just in case it fails; a diagnostic message would be a good idea too.  You should `close(fd[1]);` after the loop in the parent to indicate EOF to the child.  (Just for once, it doesn't matter if you don't detect the error return from `malloc()`; it is legitimate to pass the address of a pointer where the pointer holds NULL to the `getline()` function, and it will then try to allocate memory itself.  Of course, if the main program fails to allocate memory, it is highly likely that `getline()` will also fail to allocate memory.)

Those changes lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t child;

    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        perror("pipe");
    else if ((child = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork");
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", NULL);
        perror("oops");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        size_t nbytes = 100;
        int bytes = 0;
        char *line = (char*)malloc(nbytes+1);
        while ((bytes = getline(&line, &nbytes, stdin)) != -1)
        {
            write(fd[1], line, bytes);
        }
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This compiles without complaint under stringent compilation flags:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra xf.c -o xf
```

When run (on Mac OS X 10.7.3) with the code above (invoking `sh` without the `-i` option), things behave reasonably sanely.  You can type commands and the shell executes them.  You can type 'exit' and the shell exits, but the program you wrote (which I called `xf`) doesn't exit until I type a new command.  It then exits because of a SIGPIPE signal as it writes to the now readerless pipe.  There is no prompt from this shell because its standard input is not a terminal (it is a pipe).

When the sub-shell is run with the `-i` option, then there seems to be a fight between the job control shells about which shell is in charge of the terminal.  When I run it, I get:

```
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  503   381   372   0 Wed08PM ttys001    0:00.07 -sh
  503 21908   381   0  9:32PM ttys001    0:00.01 sh
$ ./xf
sh-3.2$ 

[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        ./xf
$ 
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  503   381   372   0 Wed08PM ttys001    0:00.07 -sh
  503 21908   381   0  9:32PM ttys001    0:00.01 sh
  503 22000 21908   0  9:36PM ttys001    0:00.00 ./xf
  503 22001 22000   0  9:36PM ttys001    0:00.00 sh -i
$ ls
awk.data           osfile-keep.c      pthread-2.c        send.c             xf
const-stuff.c      perl.data          pthread-3.c        so.8854855.sql     xf.c
fifocircle.c       piped-merge-sort.c quine.c            strandsort.c       xf.dSYM
madump.c           powa.c             recv.c             unwrap.c           xxx.sql
makefile           pthread-1.c        regress.c          vap.c              yyy.sql
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        ./xf
$ fg %1
./xf
exit
$
```

(The initial `-sh` is the login shell for my terminal window.  In that, I've run `sh` to get a sub-shell, and I've set the prompt `PS1='$ '` to make the prompt distinctive.)

AFAICT, the `sh-3.2$` prompt comes from the `sh -i` shell.  The parent shell seems to be reading input, and has dumped the `xf` program into the background, which is not very civilized of it.  The `ps -f` output doesn't show the `ps` command, which is a nuisance.  I did manage to get the `ls` command to show up in a `ps` listing in one run, and it was the child of the original shell, not the `sh -i` run by `xf`.  When I bring `xf` into the foreground, it immediately exits (presumably it reads 0 bytes from standard input, which indicates EOF, and so `getline()` returns -1, and everything shuts up shop.  The `exit` is from the `sh -i`; it echoes it.  It never got any input because the `sh` shell took command instead of letting `xf` have control of the terminal.  That's pretty excruciatingly messy.  I'm not sure why it happens like that, but it feels to me like it shouldn't happen like that.

Comment: thanks for many tips! I can't imagine that this problem is this complex. btw, I think you forgot pipe(fd) to initialize the pipe ?

Comment: Aargh! My test code behaved most peculiarly until I added it; I then forgot to update the answer!  The code should error check the `write()` system call too (it would have showed up that problem quicker).